# Options for Securing Connection Strings

Tags: security, architecture, encryption, config

Just a general architecture question.

I know that for web sites, one can use the features built in to IIS to encrypt the connection string section. However, what I am not certain of is this... If I do this and then copy the web.config to another project, will the new project still be able to decrypt the connection strings section in the config file?

Where this becomes an issue is production database access. We don't want anyone to be able to copy the config file from production into their project and have carte blanche access to the production database.

Currently the way my company does it is to store the encrypted connection string in the registry of the server, then use a home-grown tool to read the registry and decrypt the value on the fly. This prevents someone from just looking into the registry or web config to see the connection string.

Further, for thick client (WinForms, WPF, etc.) applications, this could be a little more problematic because once again, I am unsure if the IIS encryption trick will work since the applications would not be running on IIS. We currently have a kludgy solution for this which involved the same home-grown application, but reading the encrypted string from a binary file and decrypting on the fly.

It just seems very patched together, and we are looking for a better way to do it (i.e., industry standard, current technology, etc.)

So, a more general question is this...

What approaches have you used for securing your connection strings? Especially when it comes to multiple application types accessing it, encryption, etc.

Answer (score 7):

A quick Google search will show you other people's attempts at encrypting some or all of an application configuration file (i.e. Google "ecnrypting application configuration files").

But more often than not, I find that the better answer is properly securing the resource that you are concerned about (usually a database). Windows authentication is always preferred of SQL authentication, that way passwords do not need to be stored in the config file, though this may not always be an option. If you want to prevent access to a resource (especially if it's usually accessed through any sort of web layer, like a web service or a website itself), then host the resource on a different server (which is preferred anyways) and don't allow access to it from outside your internal network. If the attacker has access to your internal network, then there's usually bigger concerns than this one resource you are trying to protect.

If you are concerned about a malicious person performing an action that even your application can't perform (like dropping a database), then ensure that the credentials the application is using doesn't have that type of permission either. This obviously doesn't prevent an attack, but it can reduce the amount of damage that is done from it.

Securing information stored in a configuration file that is located on the user's machine is generally not worth the time, IMHO.  At the end of the day, the machine itself will need to be able to decrypt the information, and if the machine has the means to do it, then so does the user.  You can make it hard for the user to do it, but it's usually still doable.

This isn't really a direct answer to your question, but I hope it gets you thinking down a different path that may lead to an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding the protection of encrypted connection strings as for example presented in the article [Importing and Exporting Protected Configuration RSA Key Containers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw286t2%28VS.80%29.aspx) protected the connection string on a user-level.

This means that only the account running IIS (`NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`) can access the cryptographic keys for decrypting the connection string. Therefore this protected only against users who are able to log-on onto the server holding the web.config file. But it can be extended to limit access to certain application.

Regarding the fat client there may be a way to narrow down the interface a bit:

Define all SQL commands as stored procedures on the server and change the settings for the used user account to only allow executing those stored procedures. This would limit access to the database to operations that can be performed using the SQL login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the SQL DB account management features, with specific permissions only (e.g. at it's most abstract - allow the execution of read only SQL commands) and only from allowed hosts and/or realms.